# Linq query not compiling

Tags: c#, sql, .net, linq

I wrote a small linq query that currently doesn't compile

```
var count = (from data in Data
             join data2 in Data on data.UserId equals data2.UserId
             group data2 by data2.UserId into gr
             where gr.Max(b => b.Date) == data.Date  // data variable not available
             select data.Id).Count(); // data variable not available
```

My problem is that I cannot reuse the **data** variable after the `group by` clause. How can I achieve this?

For information, this is the `SQL` query that I'm trying to convert.

```
SELECT COUNT(data.Id)
FROM Data data
INNER JOIN
    (SELECT UserId, MAX(Date) AS MaxDate
     FROM Data
     GROUP BY UserId) g
ON data.UserId = g.UserId
AND data.Date = g.MaxDate
```

Comment: Your linq's `group by` doesn't correspond the SQL. You're grouping the join results.

Answer (score 1):

As I mentioned in the comment, the order of `group by` and `join` in your linq query doesn't match your SQL query.

If you like the query syntax, your query could look like this:

```
(from d in Data
join g in
    (from d in Data
    group d by d.UserId
    into gr
    select new { UserId = gr.Key, MaxDate = gr.Max(d => d.Date) })
on new { ID = d.UserId, Date = d.Date} equals new { ID = g.UserId, Date = g.MaxDate }
select d.Id)
.Count();
```

But it's pretty ugly and too complex. If you'll do this in-memory (linq-to-objects), you'll need to be aware of lots of allocations.

Answer (score -4):

Try following :

```
var max = (from data in Data
             join data2 in Data on data.UserId equals data2.UserId
             select new {data = data, data2 = data2})
             .GroupBy(x => x.data2.UserId)
             .Select(x => x.Max(b => b.data2.Date))
             .ToList();
```

Comment: it's not the same as the `sql`

Comment: You need to provide some more details to avoid downvotes jdweng. You have 16.6k points. I'm sure you know how to answer within SO standards.